# WPF control to render formatted raw HTML

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I'm wondering if there is a WPF control that will display nicely formatted HTML?

I want to bind a raw piece of HTML to the control and have it format the tags nicely with carriage returns and tabs etc.

Note - I do not want to display the output of the HTML string in the control like a web browser control would but just the formatted raw string itself

Comment: Unfortunately not. I'm currently just using a RichTextBox to render but this just displays as is

Comment: Yea, same issue - I would really think this would be trivial - but in WPF trivial things are stupidly hard.  Then anything that works with Telerik only works with Silverlight - not sure anyone knows what that is ... it was very successsful like Windows ME...

Sorry for the negative, I know its not helpful to yours or my cause - I just wish Microsoft would see how bad it is and fix or change it.

Answer (score -1):

WebBrowser should do what you're after.

```
<WebBrowser Name="myWebBrowser"/>
```

Use the NavigateToString method to pass HTML content.

```
myWebBrowser.NavigateToString(myHTMLContent);
```

Comment: The OP specifically said he didn't want to use a WebBrowser

Comment: Ah, I see. Is he's looking for pretty-printed HTML output?